# Implement the Paste external command to simple python script

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, csv, subprocess

I am trying to implement the command:
paste output1_transp.csv output2_transp.csv output3_transp.csv| column -s $'\t' -t

in a python script that I have created using python 2.7.6 in order to 
combine three columns in one file and afterwards save it.

The files output1_transp.csv, output2_transp.csv and output3_transp.csv have been created above from my python script.

The command works perfect in the linux terminal and prints on the screen.
However, I would love to create the combined file using my python script and afterwards saving the combined columns in a file.

I have read about    https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module 
but I was not able to find a solution.

I would be grateful for any suggestion or help.

Comment: You _could_ call the Unix `paste` and `column` commands using the `subprocess` module, but why don't you try to do this using Python's native string and list handling capabilities? Sure, it won't be quite as fast as using the `paste` and `column` compiled binaries, but that shouldn't matter unless your files are huge.

Comment: Because using lists is not much helpful in my case at this moment. My goal is to extract data from a file of millions lines from a quantum mechanics calculation and all my code so far is not based on lists. If somebody proposes me an efficient way to use subprocess i am more than okay.  I appreciate your response.